# Replace the start of string domain with new one SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to recheck all database and all tables and change the url string if there is somewhere for example  `example.ge` or `example.ge/logo/image.png`  with  `example.com` or `example.com/logo/image.png`

so i want to change in any string  `example.ge` to `example.com`

How can i perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

Hy there!

Try with SUBSTRING. You are searchig for `example.com`;
Substring takes given string and devide it to one or more strings so; `SUBSTRING("STRING",start_int,lengt_int)` in your example:

```
STRING == "example.go" 
start_int == (lengt of STRING (10))
lengt_int == null
```

Code:

```
UPDATE `YourTable`
SET `Url` = CONCAT("example.com",SUBSTRING(`Url`,10)
WHERE `Url` LIKE "%example.go%";
```

URL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it changed all the links to example.com, i wanted to replace example.ge with example.com and other parts of url remain unchanged. Anyway i did it...

Comment: This should do what you wrote... CONCAT() joins "example.com"  with your current string from 10th character on...

Comment: Yes, maybe its my fault.. didnt describe problem well. anyway i did it and thank you for support.